# How to get GPS co-ordinates of particular place from HERE map

Tags: android, gps, here-api

Actually I wanted to get GPS co-ordinates of a particular place when user long presses that place on map by using HERE Maps Android SDK. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible. Use Map#getSelectedObjects() to retrieve the list of POIs that the user has touched. If the object is an instance of MapCartoMarker, the gps coordinate of the object is stored in MapCartoMarker.

Comment: @ David Leong Thank you. But I didn't understood MapCartoMarker is this in android SDK?

Comment: Please see: 
https://developer.here.com/mobile-sdks/documentation/android-hybrid-plus/topics_api_nlp_hybrid_plus/com-here-android-mpa-mapping-mapcartomarker.html

Comment: @ David Leong Oh now I know it. Will you be able to tell how to enable POIs in maps? Because I cannot see POIs in maps using Android SDK.I have tried contacting here support but they said there it needs to be enabled. By default its disabled.

Comment: What do you mean by "enable POI in maps"? The map should be already rendering POIs that we call "carto POIs" They are the places with the small icon and name.


The number of POIs that are rendered is only a subset and best fit based on the screen size.

Comment: Anyways I solved it, I was using actually starter SDK and POIs are only visible in premium SDK. Now I switched to Premium SDK and now I am able to see all POIs. But the POIs seen on HERE map using official website is different than in SDK infact not all POIs that are on Map is available in SDK.

Comment: The HERE.com website uses tiled maps which are pre-rendered. It is difficult to compare against the runtime renderer as a server farm has far high computing power.